# Create a branch without old commits

Tags: git

I forked a repository at commit O1 to fix a bug in it. I made two commits, B1 and B2, to the master branch.

```
O1 -> B1 -> B2
```

Later, I decided to add a new feature. I added a few more commits to the master branch.

```
O1 -> B1 -> B2 -> F1 -> F2 -> F3
```

This new version, with both the bugfix and the feature, is currently in use by me.

I'd like to make a pull request to the original repository for the feature I added. However, the bugfix is entirely unrelated, and shouldn't be included. I wasn't initially expecting to ever want to share my modifications so, like a fool, I did all of this in the master branch. I have since learned my lesson.

How can I make a branch/something that contains just the feature:

```
O1 -> F1 -> F2 -> F3
```

...so that I can make a pull request with it, while also maintaining a version with both the feature and the bugfix that I can use myself?

Comment: I think you want something like `git cherry-pick`, or maybe `git rebase -i` if you want B1 and B2 to be children of F1–F3, but out of curiosity, why do you not want to make a PR for the bugfix?

Comment: @Daniel H The bugfix and the feature should be in separate pull requests. (the bugfix also seems to be specific to my environment and doesn't appear to have been a problem for the original devs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git rebase B2 F3 --onto O1
```

This basically says "Cut off the commits from `F3` down to where that branch diverged from `B2`, and paste them on top of `O1`."

Note that it doesn't matter what the current branch is when you execute this (although you can't have any outstanding changes), but if you're already on `F3`, you can omit that parameter, which defaults to the current branch:

```
git rebase B2 --onto O1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ii can be done like this

```
git rebase --onto O1 B2 F3
```

You are asking rebase F3 on top of O1 discarding revisions up to B2.

Answer (score 0):

I would do (with `master` branch checked out and `F3` being `HEAD`)

```
git checkout -b feature
git rebase -i HEAD~6
```

choose `drop` for `B1` and `B2`